# MySQL stored procedure returning undefined using express.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure getUsers in MYSQL that takes in an int and returns a table of users with user data. The stored procedure returns 1 row when I run it in phpmyadmin with a 'name' field, however when I call it from Node.js the row fields return "undefined". I feel like I must be missing something because every other table operation I do with Node.js the same way works, but when I try to call this store procedure it doesn't. Here's my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
//constants
const tableName = 'user';

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'users',
    charset : 'utf8mb4'
});

//function to insert to or retrieve data from the database
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
        let userID = req.body.userID;
        connection.query(
            "CALL `getUsers`(?)",
                [userID],
                function(err, row, field) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send({ 'success': false, 'message': 'Could not connect. ' + err});
                }
                if ( row.length > 0 ) {
                    console.log('name: ' + row[0].name);
                    res.send({ 'success': true, 'users': row });
                } else {
                    res.send({ 'success': false, 'message': 'No users found.' });
                }
        }); 
    }
});
```

the console log returns 'name: undefined', but when I run the procedure in phpmyadmin it returns the row with the correct 'name' field in it.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax should be:

`` connection.query(`CALL getUsers(?)`, [userID], (err, row, field) => {}) ``

Note the backticks vs. the way you have the double quotes.

Comment: Same issue using backticks. I think either one works because I use double quotes with my other queries and they work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to let y'all know I fixed the problem by changing row[0].name to row[0][0].name
Turns out stored procedures are unlike regular queries in that they return an array of arrays instead of just one array.